# Don't print the kafka-console-consumer warnings

Tags: apache-kafka, suppress-warnings, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to debug encrypted messages onto a Kafka cluster. Obviously these messages are full of non printable characters and are not usable on a console, so I wanted to save the output in a file like this:

```
kafka-console-consumer \
    --zookeeper 0.zookeeper.local,1.zookeeper.local \
    --max-messages 1 \
    --topic MYTOPIC > /tmp/message
```

I am unable to decrypt the resulting message, because the output contains, along with the ciphertext, warning messages such as:

```
[2016-02-24 11:52:47,488] WARN Reconnect due to socket error: null (kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer)
```

Is there a way to get one single message in a file and **NOT** embed the warnings in that file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a special logger config file for inbound console tools. Please, change the logger level from WARN to OFF in *[kafka_home]/config/tools-log4j.properties* file. The file should look like:

**tools-log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=OFF, stdout 

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
```

After it you will get only messages in console.

Comment: also useful if you want to get DEBUG output from the console consumer

Comment: You can also change `stdout` to `stderr` in each of the lines to keep log lines from being redirected to your messages file. You may also need to append the line: `log4j.appender.stderr.Target=System.err`

Comment: This saved me from unwanted warnings on my screen.

Answer (score 2):

try create new config xml file and just run again

> src/main/resources/logback.xml

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.kafka.common.metrics" level="INFO"/>
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This probably seems to be a better way as we can control the logging from the application side.