# How to print "Kafka"-Messages to console using Spring-Cloud-Stream-Binder-Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

My question is very close to [Print Kafka Stream Input out to console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327868/print-kafka-stream-input-out-to-console) with a slight difference: I am using StreamsBuilder instead of Kstreambuilder. (Unfortunately the git with the resolution is not available due to an 404 Error.)

My Listener is:

```
    @StreamListener(LoansStreams.INPUT)
    public void handleLoans(@Payload Loans loans) {


        final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream(stringSerde, stringSerde, "in-stream");
        source.flatMapValues(new ValueMapper<String, Iterable<String>>() {
            @Override
            public Iterable<String> apply(String value) {
                ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();

                // apply regex to value and for each match add it to keywords

                return keywords;
            }

        }
    }
```

The error I get is "The method stream(String, Consumed) in the type StreamsBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Serde, Serde, String)", obviously because it was part of the Kstreambuilder.

Assuming I understood correctly, I must flatmap the received message, but how do I do this?
I want to add that it is my first time using Kafka-Cloud-Stream.

My goal is to create a POC with two different microservices access different databases and "connect" both microservices via Kafka in order to apply Saga pattern (or at least start applying its principles).

In case it matter, I started Kafka with only messages to print:

```
    #log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stderr
    log4j.rootLogger=OFF, stdout 

    log4j.appender.stderr=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.stderr.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
    #log4j.appender.stderr.Target=System.err
```

Learned from [Don't print the kafka-console-consumer warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601719/dont-print-the-kafka-console-consumer-warnings)

Also, based on [KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455100/keepererrorcode-nonode-for-admin-preferred-replica-election) I am ignoring this zookeeper exception:

```
[2019-04-30 14:15:11,617] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100003793980001 type:multi cxid:0x71 zxid:0xbc txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a aborting remaining multi ops. Error Path:/admin/preferred_replica_election Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
```

Last but not least, my sender is:

```
public void sendLoan(final Loans loans) {
    log.info("Sending loans {}", loans);
    MessageChannel messageChannel = loansStreams.outboundLoans();
    messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(loans)
            .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .build());
}
```

The POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mybank</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>kafka-cloud-stream</name>
    <description>Spring Cloud Stream With Kafka</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <!-- version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Regardless of your problem, you seem to have some misunderstanding - you are mixing a message-channel `StreamListener` with a Kafka-streams binder - with that code, you will create a new `KStream` for **every message received by the listener**. You should be using one or the other, not both.

Comment: If I udnerstood correctly,  you are saying "either use StreamListener or use Kafka-stream binder". Well, can  you sumarize when use one versus another?

Comment: I added some clarifications as a comment to your other post. You are mixing the two concerns here. There are a handful of samples available at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples. Could you take a look at them and see if any of them meets your requirements?

Comment: The question you linked to should point here, but the fact that you turned off the root logger is really not a good thing if you want to log things. https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KStreamBuilder` is the old builder class that was replaced by `StreamsBuilder` (in Apache Kafka 1.0.0 release). Not only the name changed, but also method parameters.

As the error message indicates, the new method expects `stream(String, Consumed)` instead of old `stream(Serde, Serde, String)`.

Compare the corresponding upgrade guide: https://docs.confluent.io/4.0.0/streams/upgrade-guide.html#building-and-running-a-topology